# IAP fails if has hosted content but works fine if treated as normal non-consumable

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, storekit, in-app-purchase

I am attempting to implement IAP of hosted content on iOS 6.0.

Without posting a bunch of code, my code was sourced from the raywenderlich tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial
and http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/. This code works fine for purchasing normal non-consumable items.

I have created a new IAP item with hosted content, and uploaded it via xcode (using the method described in the second link above).

When I go to purchase the item, it brings up the alert and I click buy. Shortly after this my transaction fails, with case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed being invoked below:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState){
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: {

                if (transaction.downloads) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                } else {
                    // unlock features
                    //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                }    
                break;               
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed: {
                if (transaction.downloads) {
                    NSLog(@"transaction failed... but found downloads");
                }

                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored: {

                if (transaction.downloads) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                } else {
                    // unlock features
                    //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                }

                break;
            }
            default:
               break;
       }
   }
}
```

The transaction.error.code appears to be SKErrorPaymentCancelled.

If I change the nature of this IAP item in iTunesConnect to not have hosted content then the purchase completes just fine. I am at a loss as to what would cause this.

Anyone with experience with IAP hosted content know of any pitfalls I should be aware of? Could it be to do with how I created the hosted content package? I just placed everything in the Supporting Files group in xcode when creating the package - inspecting the archive package in finder shows the contents as:

/dSYMs

/Info.plist

/Products/Library/InAppPurchaseContent/ProductIDName/Contents/#content here#

/Products/Library/InAppPurchaseContent/ProductIDName/ContentInfo.plist

Is this correct? Once uploaded it says "Waiting for Screenshot" which I understand is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am experiencing the same problems on my side, for all my IAP content hosted on Apple servers I get a SKErrorPaymentCancelled error as well.
This issue seems to be coming from Apple who is currently working on it.

See there for more updates :

https://devforums.apple.com/message/839428#839428

[iPhone storekit sandbox stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522899/iphone-storekit-sandbox-stopped-working)

Comment: Was about to come here and close of the issue with the same post. Seems they've fixed it now. Cheers.