# In-App-Purchase does not work anymore

Tags: objective-c, ios, storekit

I've recently (2 weeks ago) tested successfully the In-App Pruchase functionality with some iPad products.

After Apple has updated its License Agreement, it didn't work anymore on my iPad.

Even after agreeing this agreement, the functionality doesn't work. I read some posts ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847111/error-domain-skerrordomain-code-3-userinfo-0x2a5a00-cannot-connect-to-itunes-sto), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532259/ipad-in-app-purchase-fails-with-skerrorpaymentcancelled-and-cannot-connect-to-it)) and found out, that others came across this issue too. I tried everything described in the posts but nothing worked for me. I hard-resetted the ipad (Settings -> reset settings & data), i rebuild it a few times, i looked at the developer forum, if there where any issues posted, ..

It can successfully retrieve the product data, but when a payment will be added to the default payment queue following error is being returned in the TransactionObserver:
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 UserInfo=0x2e09e0 "Cannot connect to itunes store"

I tested the same functionality on other iPhones and it worked (simply copied the classes from the iPad project to the iPhone project and created the dev. prov. profile).

To completely understand my situation, i had to renew my dev account and there i accidently renewed my certificate. So i created a new prov. profiles for my apps.

I than tested it on another iPad but it also didn't work. I also created a new provi. profile and a new product, cleard all and rebuilt it to test it on the ipad, but it always keeps returning the same error.

So it seems that the problem is in my iPad project, but what can i do? I copied the source code from Apples StoreKit Guide and modified it (a little bit) so it can manage the purchases with our server. I also changed the code sign identity (project and target) to build it with the correct dev. prov. profile. But what else can i do?

Please help!

Thanks & BR
Nic

Comment: I also created a new test user account, but before i'm getting prompted to enter the account data i get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works! It was a little bit unusual but it works!

1. I reviewed the provisioning profile. The certivicate was unchecked, so I rechecked it, downloaded it and installed (double clicked) it
2. Deleted the app and all installed porvisioning profiles from my ipad
3. Set the code signing identifier (in the target and the project setting) in the last hand in project (prev. version of the app) and rebuilt (clear all, build) it
4. Set the code signing identifier of the current project and rebuilt it

And the test in app purchase worked.

Hope it helps anyone!

BR
Nic

Answer (score 1):

Your provisoning profile is made for inapp ?

Sometimes the Apple sandbox server respons error but not during long period.

Are you unlog from your iTunes account in the iPad setting befor buy in your sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged off with the official itunes login and the provisioning profile is not a team provisioning profile (with the * at the end, which is managed by xcode)